# Eclipse PMD Can't find basic.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno, pmd

When attempting to run [pmd](/questions/tagged/pmd) for a project in Eclipse/Juno, I am getting this error.

```
An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode".
Couldn't find the class Can't find resource rulesets/basic.xml.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL or is on the CLASSPATH.  Here's the current classpath: C:\eclipsejuno\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 10):

I have seen this problem with the command line version as well. In the latest version the classpath is `rulesets/java/basic.xml`

It seems they changed the default paths between versions. You either need to manually update your paths in the PMD config, or update to the latest version.

Comment: hi... i am getting the same error. I manually updated path from 
    <rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml" /> to 
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml" /> but to no avail. Still getting the same error

Comment: Also updating and even unistall/install the plugin does not solve the issue for me! The error popup still apearing when eclipse build project

Answer (score 4):

If ".pmd" file exists in your project and referent with ruleset.xml, you can solve your issue choosing between the above solutions.

1. delete .pmd file
2. open your ruleset.xml, and your configuration according this sample

```xml
<rule ref="rulesets/basic.xml" />
```

TO

```xml
<rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The advice with changing rulesets/ to rulesets/java/ helped me, but I had to also change one rule from:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml/UnusedModifier">
  <priority>5</priority>
</rule>
```

to

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedModifier">
  <priority>5</priority>
</rule>
```

Here is my PMD configuration file from sonar which is working for me with PMD-plugin 4.0.2.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         name="pmd-eclipse"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnusedNullCheckInEquals">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/StringInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/ConstructorCallsOverridableMethod">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingNPE">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidRethrowingException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/ReplaceEnumerationWithIterator">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml/AvoidArrayLoops">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedFormalParameter">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/ClassCastExceptionWithToArray">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidThrowingNullPointerException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedPrivateField">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/CompareObjectsWithEquals">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UseIndexOfChar">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/BigIntegerInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/FinalFieldCouldBeStatic">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/SuspiciousEqualsMethodName">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/InstantiationToGetClass">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/SuspiciousHashcodeMethodName">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/coupling.xml/LooseCoupling">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedLocalVariable">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UnnecessaryCaseChange">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/SingularField">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/CloseResource">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/AvoidCatchingThrowable">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/CollapsibleIfStatements">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UselessOperationOnImmutable">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/clone.xml/CloneMethodMustImplementCloneable">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UselessOverridingMethod">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedModifier">
    <priority>5</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/PreserveStackTrace">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml/UseArraysAsList">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/EqualsNull">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/BrokenNullCheck">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-jakarta-commons.xml/UseCorrectExceptionLogging">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/InefficientStringBuffering">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/sunsecure.xml/ArrayIsStoredDirectly">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/FinalizeOverloaded">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/controversial.xml/DontImportSun">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml/DontImportJavaLang">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/MissingStaticMethodInNonInstantiatableClass">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/StringBufferInstantiationWithChar">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/optimizations.xml/UseArrayListInsteadOfVector">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/StringToString">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/SimplifyConditional">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/ReplaceVectorWithList">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml/NcssMethodCount">
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
      <property name="minimum" value="50" />
    </properties>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml/AvoidPrintStackTrace">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/MethodWithSameNameAsEnclosingClass">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/naming.xml/SuspiciousConstantFieldName">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml/NcssTypeCount">
    <priority>3</priority>
    <properties>
      <property name="minimum" value="800" />
    </properties>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/AvoidInstanceofChecksInCatchClause">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/IntegerInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/AvoidAssertAsIdentifier">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/UnnecessaryLocalBeforeReturn">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/AvoidCallingFinalize">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/BooleanInstantiation">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnconditionalIfStatement">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/clone.xml/CloneThrowsCloneNotSupportedException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/ReplaceHashtableWithMap">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/AvoidDecimalLiteralsInBigDecimalConstructor">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/EmptyFinalizer">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/IdempotentOperations">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/ExceptionAsFlowControl">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/finalizers.xml/FinalizeDoesNotCallSuperFinalize">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UseStringBufferLength">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/migrating.xml/AvoidEnumAsIdentifier">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/logging-java.xml/SystemPrintln">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/UselessStringValueOf">
    <priority>4</priority>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml/AvoidDuplicateLiterals">
    <priority>3</priority>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error when trying to update Maven project in Eclipse. The problem for me was that I was using two different PMDs, one installed as Eclipse plugin and another one downloaded by Maven from the pom.xml file of a parent project. So what I needed to do was to uninstall Eclipse's PMD plugin and after that didn't get the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have my custom pmdRuleSet.xml and it looks like:

```
<rule ref="pmd-rulesets/java/codesize.xml/ExcessiveMethodLength">
<properties>
    <property name="minimum" value="10"/>
</properties>
```

And it throws the error, if I change "pmd-rulesets" to "ruleset", and the path in the pmdRuleSet.xml obviously, then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

if you have to face a complex project setup you could use this line to convert every .pmd file

```
find . -name .pmd -exec sed -i.bak 's/rulesets\/basic.xml/rulesets\/java\/basic.xml/g' {} \;
```